# Specifying multiple/wild card reply urls in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have a news application where the reply url is not fixed. And it could be anything in our system. Azure AD B2C currently supports only 20 reply urls in app so we cant add more reply urls as well.

So we either need 
1. Wild card reply urls OR 
2. some way to have as many reply urls as we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild card reply urls have a potential threat

The threat related to this is called “Open Redirector” and is discussed in sections [4.1.5 (Threat: Open Redirectors on Client)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.1.5) and [4.2.4 (Threat: Open Redirector)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.2.4) of [RFC 6819 (OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819). The mitigation is specified in section [5.2.3.5 (Validate Pre-Registered “redirect_uri”).](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.3.5)

When the number of reply URLs is large and based on some input parameters, it is advisable to consider the following practice:

- Create a ‘common’ reply URL per application, and register it in AAD B2C. All replies from AAD B2C will go to this reply URL.
- The application can store branding related information on the local client (e.g. session cookie, HTML5 local storage).
- After an authorization request, Azure AD B2C will send the response back on the ‘common’ reply URL.
- At this point, the application can read the local storage and redirect to the correct URL based on the parameters stored locally.

This approach is also more scalable because every reply URL does not need to be registered with the application. Likewise when some branding is removed from the aplication, there is no management task to remember to delete that reply URL from the application.

With some applications (e.g. news websites) this is the only practical approach to avoid maintaining thousands (if not) of reply URLs in the directory.